# SSIS Error - No object exists with ID 0

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I deployed an SSIS 2016 package last week after updating an SQL statement. I deployed by simply right clicking the package in MVS and choosing deploy. 
It's run properly for the last week, but last night we got errors. The error description is simply No Object exists with ID 0.
I took a quick look at my code, and there's a Script Transformation that calls C# with PipelineVersion==0. It's part of an error handler so, it wouldn't be called regularly. Could this be the cause of my error?
And what can I do in my deployment to avoid this error?

Comment: Can you get the error to happen in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, when I run the code in Visual Studio, it stops at the Script Transformation. In progress I see the error No Object exists with the ID 0.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to resolve the issue by opening the script, rebuilding it, and rerunning the SSIS.
I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done to avoid this issue in the future. It makes me look pretty bad to the client when this happens in production.